# Write mySQL query to CSV utf-8 file in python?

Tags: python, utf-8, export-to-csv

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import csv

db_user = 'root'
db_pass = 'FGifPYRMcuQYF3dh'
db_schema = 'site1.local'
dbs = {
     'db1': 'localhost'

}

def export_csv_accounts():
    con = None
    for dbnames in dbs:
         con = mdb.connect(dbs[dbnames], db_user, db_pass, db_schema)
         cur = con.cursor()
         db_query = "select * from tabAccount;"
         cur.execute(db_query)
         rows = cur.fetchall()
         out_file = csv.writer(open("/home/"+dbs[dbnames] + '_Accounts.csv', "wb"))
         columns = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
         out_file.writerow(columns)
         out_file.writerows(rows)
    con.close()
    return "Ok"
```

Error in file csv
"Company","Lâm Ch?n Huy","Vietnam"
I have a error with UTF-8 file.
How to use UTF-8 for csv file ?

Comment: Have you tried googling `How to use UTF-8 for csv file`?

Answer (score 0):

Python 2's `csv` module does not handle Unicode CSV files properly, as you can [see in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Try using the `UnicodeWriter` and `UnicodeReader` classes given in [the code examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Try encode the text before write to file:

Ex: This is what I used for converting xls file to csv file. Hope it helps

```
Outputlocation = ....
your_csv_file = open(''.join([Outputlocation,'.csv']), 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
    wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])
your_csv_file.close()
```